# How to calculate O(nlogn) iterative merge sort time complexity step by step using sigma notation

Tags: algorithm, merge, time-complexity, mergesort

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r); 

int min(int x, int y) { return (x<y)? x :y; } 

void mergeSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int curr_size;  
   int left_start; 

   for (curr_size=1; curr_size<=n-1; curr_size = 2*curr_size) 

   { 
       for (left_start=0; left_start<n-1; left_start += 2*curr_size) 

       {
           int mid = min(left_start + curr_size - 1, n-1);

           int right_end = min(left_start + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1); 

           merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end); 

       } 
   } 
} 

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) 
{ 

    int i, j, k; 
    int n1 = m - l + 1; 
    int n2 =  r - m;
    int L[n1], R[n2]; 
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j]; 

    i = 0; 
    j = 0; 
    k = l; 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) 
    { 
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) 
        {
            arr[k] = L[i]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else
        { 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 

    } 
    while (i < n1) 

    { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++;
    } 
    while (j < n2) 

    { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
}
```

I couldn't figure out O(nlogn) time complexity of the iterative merge sort.
I need to calculate myself using steps like we do in normal calculation of time complexities. Calculations of Recursive merge sort is available but i couldn't find and figure out how to solve for iterative one.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming n is a power of 2, there's n merges of size 1, and n/2 merges of size 2, n/4 merges of size 4, and so on, down to 1 merge of size n.

The cost of a merge of size k is linear in k.

So the total cost is n + n/2 * 2 + n/4 * 4 + ... + 1 * n = n log_2 n.